# AWS Lambda: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, classnotfoundexception

I am getting this message and I have no idea how to resolve it. Searched online and tried to implement their suggestion, but no luck yet.
[image]

I basically followed the instructions specified in this link -
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html

But instead of uploading the project using the AWS Management Console embedded in Eclipse, I tried to create a zip of my project and upload it to the AWS web console.

Below is structure of my project -
[image]

That is it!! There is nothing fancy that I am trying to do here. It is just a HelloWorld example in Lambda.

Now, this is how I am creating the zip file, which is pretty straight forward in Eclipse -
[image]

Once the zip is created I uploaded it to AWS Web console under the code tab -
[image]

The Configuration tab looks something like this -
[image]

Now when I am clicking the Test button it is unable to find the example.Hello class.

How come it is becoming so difficult for the Lambda Function to find this class? Can anyone suggest what possibly is going wrong in this execution??

Also attached the log statement, in case it helps -

[image]

Comment: I resolved this issue, by making the following changes -
First,
I have changed the method signature to ::
public String handleRequest(Map<String,Object> input, Context context)
::
and second, instead of exporting it to zip I exported it to normal jar, after making those two changes AWS Lambda was able to find the class. Hope this helps and save your time.

Comment: Just wanna chime in that i tried the same thing and just uploaded the uber jar file to s3 instead of a zipped package of it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me.

1. Go to your lambda function in AWS Console
2. Click on Code tab.
3. Edit Run time settings
4. Replace example.Hello::handleRequest with full class path of your stream handler. For example com.abc.company.app.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
5. Save it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, what worked for me was if you're running this from eclipse with maven, ensure you have the following plugin in your pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events</exclude>
              <exclude>com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </artifactSet>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then run the project with: `mvn package shade:shade` to generate the jar artifacts in your target directory.  After that, eclipse should upload the correct jar to lambda.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and was wondering ... what is "shade" and why do you think this solved the problem? Sorry but I'm a bit out of my depths when it comes to Java.

Comment: Shade plugin builds JAR with all dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Note that the generic type of your RequestHandler interface is different from the default one :

default: `public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Object, String>`

yours: `public class Hello implements RequestHandler<String, String>`

The reason why it is giving ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maven-shade-plugin, you can use **spring-boot-maven-plugin** plugin with spring-boot-thin-layout dependency and other configurations as shown in below plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.26.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

PS:

1. remove maven-shade-plugin
2. I've refereed [Official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/aws.html#thin-jar) of spring.cloud.io

Comment: Actually, *spring-boot-maven-plugin* caused `ClassNotFoundException` for the all the classes in the project, while *maven-shade-plugin* worked just fine. Also, AWS recommends shade -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html

Answer (score 0):

**Non-Maven answer**

The reason why it's not working is because Lambda is expecting compiled `*.class` files in the zip. Unfortunately it won't compile the Java files for you.

I was getting the same error message as you when trying to upload a standalone Java file (not using Maven or Gradle or anything else). Although not very well-documented, I noticed this subtle detail on [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html) hinting at the class files (the grep part):

> Example test-zip.sh
>
> ```
> mkdir -p expanded
> unzip path/to/my/function.zip -d expanded
> find ./expanded/lib -name '*.jar' | xargs -n1 zipinfo -1 | grep '.*.class' | >sort | uniq -c | sort
> ```

When I uploaded a zip file with just the class file, Lambda ended up finding the file correctly. Although, I had to remove the AWS `Context` parameter just for it to compile, so Lambda produced a different error message saying the handler method signature didn't match (it found the file though).

Answer (score 0):

Sample java Code: filename : Main.java

```
package org.example;   
public class Main implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String> {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> event, Context context) {
...}
...}
```

Set configuration as follows:

**Handler**

> org.example.Main::handleRequest