# AWS Lambda ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am having trouble when lambda function is called on dynamoDB update.
i have checked 
[AWS Lambda: ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943897/aws-lambda-classnotfoundexception)
and 
[AWS Lambda NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782980/aws-lambda-noclassdeffounderror)
but no success.

i am writing this lambda function to call when there is any update in dynamo . i followed this tutorial.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-dynamodb-create-package.html

All the thing have been done successfully but the problem is when i update dynamodb and check the logs for AWS Cloud watch there is an exception.

```
Error loading method handleRequest on class com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/DynamodbEvent
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
```

my java code is.

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent.DynamodbStreamRecord;


public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : ddbEvent.getRecords()){
               System.out.println(record.getEventID());
               System.out.println(record.getEventName());
               System.out.println(record.getDynamodb().toString());

            }
            return "Successfully processed " + ddbEvent.getRecords().size() + " records.";
    }

}
```

my pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.amazonaws.lambda</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
      <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.321</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

i am naming my handler as `com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler::handleRequest`

i have checked all the things are fine but still it is giving me error on `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent` this class is in aws sdk.

dependency tree.
[image]

Comment: could you provide the maven dependency tree: `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @ilopezluna please check the dependency tree

Answer (score 1):

You have to build your project via Maven by using the following command: `mvn clean package`. Then go to `target` directory where you can find your built jar file.

When you upload the jar file to AWS Lambda you have to upload the jar file which includes all dependencies (`aws-lambda-java-events` in your example). Please see the screen for your example:

[image]

In your case, you have to upload `demo-1.0.0.jar` instead of `original-demo-1.0.0.jar`.

Comment: i am creating jar file using. File->Export->Jar File in Eclipse. i decompiled the jar file and yes there is no dependency. how can i make this full jar file with all the dependencies

Comment: please use `mvn clean package` command since you use maven and have a pom file. After that, open target directory in your project and you will see these files.

Answer (score 0):

If everything's fine, even package name and generated JAR & all and still someone's facing an error then you can add following configurations to the maven-plugin..

instead of maven-shade-plugin, I'm using **spring-boot-maven-plugin** plugin with following configs.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.26.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
    <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
        </transformer>
    </transformers>
</configuration>
```

and then you can run

```
./mvnw clean package
```

or if you're using STS/Eclipse, then run Maven build.. with goals **clean package**

This will generate a jar file in KB in your target folder and you can use this JAR to deploy on AWS lambda code.

PS:

1. remove maven-shade-plugin
2. I've refereed [Official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/aws.html#thin-jar) of spring.cloud.io