# AWS lambda Project

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a new AWS lambda project using eclipse and uploaded that code to S3 bucket. Then I created and mapped this AWS project to lambda using uploading code from S3 bucket and also changed the handler to that of mine in application. When testing this I am getting :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: com.amazonaws.lambda.test.LambdaFunctionHandler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda: ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943897/aws-lambda-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got it resolved.The problem was with the way I created my jar file.I was exporting and creating jar which was not the proper way.Now I'm doing that by running maven install and now my issue got resolved.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question if you do not think it will be of benefit to other readers.